# Continuous node in flowchart using Tikz

Tags: nodes, tikz-pgf

How can I make the nodes connected without any block using Tikz? For example, I was trying to connect the arrows that returns to the do-loop when the decision making box (named as *Condn*) returns *no*. However, you can see in the Latex code below that the two arrows are disconnected! Any help?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, shadows}

\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30, drop shadow]
\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=3cm, draw=black, fill=orange!30]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]

\node (start) [startstop] {Start};
\node (in1) [io, below of=start] {Input};
\node (pro1) [process, below of=in1] {Process 1};
\node (dec1) [decision, below of=pro1, yshift=-0.5cm] {Condn};
%\node (pro2b) [process, right of=dec1, xshift=2cm] {};
\node (pro2b) [arrow, right of=dec1, xshift=3cm] {};
\node (out1) [io, below of=dec1] {Output};
\node (stop) [startstop, below of=out1] {Stop};

\draw [arrow] (start) -- (in1);
\draw [arrow] (in1) -- (pro1);
\draw [arrow] (pro1) -- (dec1);
\draw [arrow] (dec1) -- node[anchor=west] {yes} (out1);
\draw [arrow] (dec1) -- node[anchor=south] {no} (pro2b);
\draw [arrow] (pro2b) |- (pro1);
      % \path[-,draw] (dec1) -| node{} (inv.north);
      % \path[line]{} (inv.north) |- node[above]{no} (pro1);
\draw [arrow] (dec1) -- (out1);
\draw [arrow] (out1) -- (stop);


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I am attaching my output as well (Modified after a sample code found online).

[image]

Answer (score 6):

There are various solutions to this problem. You can draw the path completely inserting an empty node with the label above:

```
\draw [arrow] (dec1.east) -- ++(5em,0) node[above] {no}
                          -- ++(5em,0) |- (pro1.east);
```

so that the whole picture draws like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]

\node (start) [startstop] {Start};
\node (in1) [io, below of=start] {Input};
\node (pro1) [process, below of=in1] {Process 1};
\node (dec1) [decision, below of=pro1, yshift=-0.5cm] {Condn};
\node (pro2b) [arrow, right of=dec1, xshift=3cm] {};
\node (out1) [io, below of=dec1] {Output};
\node (stop) [startstop, below of=out1] {Stop};

\draw [arrow] (start) -- (in1);
\draw [arrow] (in1) -- (pro1);
\draw [arrow] (pro1) -- (dec1);
\draw [arrow] (dec1) -- node[anchor=west] {yes} (out1);
\draw [arrow] (dec1.east) -- ++(5em,0) node[above] {no}
                          -- ++(5em,0) |- (pro1.east);
\draw [arrow] (dec1) -- (out1);
\draw [arrow] (out1) -- (stop);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have added an extra instruction box. However, the arrow below the decision box turns out to be very small and it also overlaps! Any way to extend the arrow distinguishably?

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, shadows}

\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30, drop shadow]
\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=3cm, draw=black, fill=orange!30]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]

\node (start) [startstop] {Start};
\node (in1) [io, below of=start] {Input};
\node (pro1) [process, below of=in1] {Process 1};
\node (pro2) [process, below of=pro1] {Process 2};
\node (dec1) [decision, below of=pro2, yshift=-0.5cm] {Is $X-Y=Z$ ?};
\node (out1) [io, below of=dec1] {Output};
\node (stop) [startstop, below of=out1] {Stop};

\draw [arrow] (start) -- (in1);
\draw [arrow] (in1) -- (pro1);
\draw [arrow] (pro1) -- (pro2);
\draw [arrow] (pro2) -- (dec1);
\draw [arrow] (dec1) -- node[anchor=west] {yes} (out1);
\draw [arrow] (dec1.east) -- ++(5em,0) node[above] {no}
                          -- ++(5em,0) |- (pro1.east);
\draw [arrow] (dec1) -- (out1);
\draw [arrow] (out1) -- (stop);


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]